# Ubuntu 12.04 - Install 64 bit version instead of already installed 32 bit - system is not booting off CD Rom

Tags: 12.04

I had already installed the 32 bit version of 12.04 Ubuntu (new install 2 weeks back) to test it out and now want to re-install the 64 bit version to maximize my PC processing power with quad core. Issue: when I am booting up from DVD, I am not getting the option for fresh install.

Comment: have you deleted the ubuntu partition?? it might be there thats wat is being detected..

Comment: I have not deleted the ubuntu partition. How do you do that?

Comment: Open Windows press window key+r for opening run , and enter"diskmgmt.msc" then delete the partition in which you have installed it previously .. after that u may need to boot repair and then you can install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a live session using the DVD. Then start **gparted** and remove the 32-bit 12.04 partition(s). Now proceed with the install.